# I want to give monthly subscription to my android application

Tags: android, subscriptions

I have an application in in which initially for a month its free and after 30 days its paid.. n every month the user needs to subscribe for the services. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloudware City has an API which can be called from anything that can talk to it over the web, be it a web app or native app on a device as long as it can talk over http/https. There is an integration kit for Silverlight, but not Android natively, but the documentation is there for anyone feeling up to writing the code to integrate :)

It is the service that does exactly as Alexander says - send it a username/password and it'll tell you if valid or not, and how long to run until expiry, and how many other subscriptions the user may have subscribed to (e.g. tiered subscriptions or multiple products.

Cloudware City http://cloudwarecity.com/vendor makes it easy to offer free or paid subscriptions to any web app, service or content, and handles sales, marketing, authentication, subscriptions/account management, recurring billing and some other nifty features.

Answer (score 1):

You write code which does that..
There is nothing in the Android API that can do this for you (afaik).
You need to implement some kind of mechanism which communicates with a service and askes if the subscription is still valid or not.

Comment: any providers give us this service?

Comment: Ya finally i have used paypal api as well as webservices to achieve this finctionality

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Android Market Licensing](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html) which provides a service to check up on the status of a license (allowing free trials), and [In-app billing](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html) which lets you charge for stuff. They're both quite new but a combination of these may do the job.

Comment: it is very costly.. almost takes 40% of your income